Nested async call how to handle in NEST js using typeORM
I have a service like below and I want to do lots of different validations before creating a task. How can I handle the nested async calls?
I tried the code below and getDataForFirstValidation function gives a null response.
If I write the query inside the firstValidation function it's working.
seems like async/await is taking time to fulfill, by that time my console is printing the null value.
What is the best way to handle this type of call?
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Task } from './task.entity';
import { TaskStatus } from './task-status.enum';
import { CreateTaskDto } from './dto/create-task.dto';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Task)
    private tasksRepository: Repository<Task>,
  ) {}

  async getAllTasks(): Promise<Task[]> {
    return this.tasksRepository.find();
  }

  async createTask(createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto): Promise<Task> {
    const { title, description } = createTaskDto;
    const validated = this.doValidation(createTaskDto);
    if(validated){
    const task = this.tasksRepository.create({
      title,
      description,
      status: TaskStatus.OPEN,
    });

    await this.tasksRepository.save(task);
    return task;
    }
    else
    {
      throw new Error("Validation failed")
    }
  }

  async doValidation(createTaskDto): Promise<void> {
    const firstValidationResult = await this.firstValidation(createTaskDto);
    // Handle the result of the first validation
  }

  private async firstValidation(createTaskDto): Promise<any> {
    
    const dbResponse = await this.getDataForFirstValidation(createTaskDto);
    // it is taking some time to get the response here
    if(dbResponse.title != 'KRL')
    {
       throw new Error("title should not be KRL")
     } 

    return true;
  }

  private async getDataForFirstValidation(createTaskDto): Promise<Task> {
    const {title:dtotitle} = createTaskDto
    const response = await this.tasksRepository.findOne({ where: { title:dtotitle } });
    return response;
  }
}


Can you provide the query you are using inside the tasksRepository.findOne

it is a simple Where condition. I updated the question

Can you provide the result after putting console on every variable?

it is always null

It's returning null because the response of your query is null, if it was related to a Promise problem the response wouldn't be null, it would probably be a Promise<pending>

it is showing promise only

What is the best way of handling this

Your async/await calls are correct, please provide more information it seems the code you are submitting is not complete

Try putting await before this.doValidation function.
async createTask(createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto): Promise<Task> {
const { title, description } = createTaskDto;
const validated = await this.doValidation(createTaskDto); <-- put await here
if(validated){
const task = this.tasksRepository.create({
  title,
  description,
  status: TaskStatus.OPEN,
});

await this.tasksRepository.save(task);
return task;
}
else
{
  throw new Error("Validation failed")
}
}

